# Armes Tuk Tuk - Spread & Origin

Tags: etymology, phrase

I have recently heard the following conversation:

> Alice: Es gab keine Milch mehr, also musste ich meine Cornflakes mit Wasser machen
>
> Bob: Och du armes Tuk-Tuk

Everybody seemed to understand the meaning of Bob's reply. But what is the origin of this phrase? It sounds very random to me. Is it a quote of sorts? A quick google search was inconclusive.

I am also curious to know if this is a regional phrase or widespread among german speaking communities.

---

### Edit:

When I heard it the phrase was used among a group of young adults. I interpreted it as a form of calling somebody childish in a kind of lighthearted way. This happened in NRW.

Comment: First time i hear this, but it is pretty clear what's meant: a poor little being being forced to break the habits for a while, causing some inconvenience but not a lasting reduction in life quality. Will incorporate "Tuk-Tuk" in my passive vocabulary :-)

Comment: I never heard this (North Bavaria) and would consider it as  baby-talk vocabulary formed while speaking (probably analogous to Wau-wau). Assuming an etymology for it seems already somewhat ambitious.

Comment: I, coming from the Berlin–Brandenburg region, have never heard _Tuk-Tuk_ before. In addition, I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: Might it be a regional thing? I heard this in NRW.

Comment: You probably won't find a clear derivation because that may not exist. It is a somewhat ironical but not insulting remark with a diminuitive, like "Oh you poor little thing". May even be meant amicably, depends on situation. There is probably no deeper sense in this ...

Comment: "armes Tuck-Tuck" ist im Ruhrgebiet ziemlich verbreitet

Comment: I am German and I know this sentence for a long while. My grandma took me in her arms as I was a child and said: “Du armes Tuck-Tuck” when I was sad about something whats not that seriously, actually.
She shown to me “I understand you, my love, but’s not a big thing.” I love her for it, until today.
If I having a mood today, I’m telling people: “I’m just a Tuck-Tuck” my best friends then know, I need a hug.

Comment: Vergleiche auch Hascherl: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hascherl

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all this has nothing to do with an auto-rickshaw (Tuk-Tuk).

[Versuch eines bremisch-niedersächsischen Wörterbuchs: T-Z](https://books.google.de/books?id=WcAqAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=tuk%20tuk%20huhn&source=bl&ots=VUJbLCHPYT&sig=ACfU3U1s6jEC8KL_LqCLMWxfXLj1XUS8cw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRkMzDt4boAhXK0aQKHcKZB28Q6AEwCXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=tuk%20tuk%20huhn&f=false) from 1771 says Tuk/Tuck is

> ein Wort, womit man die Hühner lockt. Es ahmt die Stimme nach, womit der Hahn die Hennen ruft. Daher nennen die Kinder ein Huhn Tukhoon[sic].

It's kind of an onomatopoeia like *wau* (dog) or *miau* (cat) and used like *miez* (for cats) to attract chicken, [still](https://www.die-glocke.de/lokalnachrichten/kreisguetersloh/Luxusherberge-fuer-Zwerghuehner-und-Co-e46b8f57-34a8-4dc0-8ed4-7cee5ad78532-ds) [used](https://books.google.de/books?id=ubkpDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT18&lpg=PT18&dq=tuk%20tuk%20huhn&source=bl&ots=Gs-ahXJEuf&sig=ACfU3U15fsjWqquvs0-OuWtIigjwymZgXQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiouuuivIboAhWKMewKHWJfDfk4ChDoATAAegQIBxAB#v=onepage&q=tuk%20tuk%20huhn%20-restaurant%20-asien&f=false) [today](https://www.huehner-haltung.de/haltung/verhalten/lautesprache/) and listed in the [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/tucktuck).

As @guidot assumed in the comments "Tuktuk/Tucktuck" like "Wauwau" are toddler language. And while a Wauwau is a dog, a Tuktuk seems to be a chicken.

(a personal note: I asked a few people today and everyone knew "Armes Tuktuk", but no one knew, what a Tuktuk is.)

And what about the idiom? [This site](https://www.fremdwort.de/suchen/bedeutung/armes-tuk-tuk#) says it's known in the northern Ruhr Area and north Germany. It explains it as:

> Der Ausdruck ist in Anlehnung des Lebens eines Huhnes entstanden. Ein Huhn legt fleißig Eier und anschliessend wird es verspeisst. "Armes Tuck-Tuck!"
>
> The expression is based on the life of a chicken. A chicken lays eggs diligently and then it is eaten. "Unfortunate Chicken!"

Maybe that's the origin, but I know similar idioms like

> Armes Hasi

Or it's just a variant of

> [Du Ärmster](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~Ach%2C%20du%20%C3%84rmster%20%2F%20du%20%C3%84rmste%21&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%2525252525252525255B%2525252525252525255D)

Comment: I never heard a chicken being called "tuktuk", I only know the word "putput" for chicken

Comment: Vergleiche auch [openthesaurus](https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/edit/32542).

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of an animal sound - but baby chicken go "piep-piep" in German.

Then there is `tuckern`:

> ein Lastkahn **tuckerte** gemächlich stromauf

("a tugboat was gently puffing its way up the stream")

Cf. **Tuk-Tuk** as name for a motorized rickshaw, also called *baby taxi*.

So *tuk-tuk* is like an universal animal sound, made by a non-animal, for about 150 years now,

---

Duden even has **tucktuck** as a call for chicken.

I agree *Tuk-Tuk* is not really a german word, but if a mother sees her child running out of food (or fuel), it is quite natural to think or say "tucktuck". Baby talk with some reason behind it.

---

And in the context of a group of young people, with Bob saying 
***Tucktuck*** to Alice --- it is all the same as with real babies. ***Cornflakes with water*** has to make you cry. It is a penalty kick Bob has *verwandelt*.

Comment: "So tuk-tuk is like an universal animal sound, made by a non-animal" - the logic of this statement escapes me.

Comment: Like Choo-Choo-Train. Tschu-tschu-Bahn. But that was steam engines. Simple combustion engines go tuk-tuk all over the world, more uniform than roosters go *kikeriki*

Comment: Yes, no doubt about that. I just fail to see how something that is explicitly made by a non-animal can be an "animal sound".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper that should mean it is an immitative call that is not exclusively limited to calling chicken anymore. Actually, if German *t[un]* is English *d[o]*, then *tuk-tuk* should be from the *duk-duck?* (rather *nak nak nak* in German). Is there such a call in English? What a surreal topic, to be honest. *Ente-Ente* just does not roll of the tongue so nicely.